# How to get date difference statistics by group with TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table with columns of product and sold date, and want to query the statistics of sold interval of each product group(max interval, min interval ...) , is there any good advice to make it, appreciate~

```
Prod    SaleDate
-------------------
A       2013-02-05
D       2013-02-24
B       2013-03-01
A       2013-03-12
D       2013-03-22
A       2013-04-03
D       2013-04-08 
. . .
```

---

Sold interval means days interval between two adjacent date.

Sold interval of A:
    DATEDIFF(d, '2013-02-05', '2013-03-12')
    DATEDIFF(d, '2013-03-12', '2013-04-03')
    ...

Sold interval of D:
    DATEDIFF(d, '2013-02-24', '2013-03-22')
    DATEDIFF(d, '2013-03-22', '2013-04-08')

---

and I want get the average, max and min value of sold interval.

```
Prod    IntervalAvg     IntervalMax    IntervalMin
-----------------------------------------------------
A       xxx             xxx            xxx
B       xxx             xxx            xxx
C
. . .
```

Comment: Can you post a clearer example?

Comment: Sample schema would help.  I dont understand what you want from the description and output.  Expand it to have more rows so we can see what you want.

Comment: So, for each product, you want to order the SaleDates and then calculate the period between each pair of dates, and that period is the Interval on which you want to generate the min/max/ave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Kahn's answer give me a hint. I re-implement my code for sql server 2000 by "left outer join".

```
DECLARE @DATA TABLE (Prod CHAR(1), SaleDate SMALLDATETIME)
INSERT INTO @DATA VALUES ('A','2013-02-05')
INSERT INTO @DATA VALUES ('D','2013-02-24')
INSERT INTO @DATA VALUES ('B','2013-03-01')
INSERT INTO @DATA VALUES ('A','2013-03-12')
INSERT INTO @DATA VALUES ('D','2013-03-22')
INSERT INTO @DATA VALUES ('A','2013-04-03')
INSERT INTO @DATA VALUES ('D','2013-04-08')


SELECT     
t.Prod
, MAX(t.Interval) IntervalMax
, MIN(t.Interval) IntervalMin
, AVG(t.Interval) IntervalAvg

FROM 
(
    SELECT t1.*, DATEDIFF(dd, MAX(t2.SaleDate), t1.SaleDate) Interval
    FROM @DATA t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @DATA t2 ON t1.Prod = t2.Prod AND t1.SaleDate > t2.SaleDate
    GROUP BY t1.Prod, t1.SaleDate
)t
GROUP BY t.Prod
ORDER BY t.Prod
```

Comment: I actually like this better than my own. Simplicity is always a good thing, and yours really got that right. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way that should work:

```
-- Test data
DECLARE @DATA TABLE (Prod CHAR(1), SaleDate DATE)
INSERT INTO @DATA VALUES ('A','2013-02-05')
,('D','2013-02-24')
,('B','2013-03-01')
,('A','2013-03-12')
,('D','2013-03-22')
,('A','2013-04-03')
,('D','2013-04-08')

-- Actual query
;WITH CTE AS 
    (SELECT D.*, CA.NextSaleDate
        , DATEDIFF(DD, SaleDate, NextSaleDate) DDiff
    FROM @DATA D
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT MIN(SaleDate) NextSaleDate FROM @DATA B WHERE B.Prod = D.Prod AND B.SaleDate > D.SaleDate) CA)
SELECT DISTINCT Prod, AvgInterval, MaxInterval, MinInterval
FROM CTE C
CROSS APPLY (SELECT AVG(DDiff) AvgInterval, MAX(DDiff) MaxInterval, MIN(DDiff) MinInterval FROM CTE B WHERE B.Prod = C.Prod) CA
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! Looks what I am looking for, but is there any alternate way to replace APPLY on sql server 2000.